# Two magento installations and login problem

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed two magento s in same server on main domain and sub domain as follows. `www.domain.com` and `www.domain.com/subdomain`. Those two magento s are active and use for different purposes. When one user use these two links user cannot logged to the second magento from same browser. So user should move to the incognito mode to log in to the second magento. How to fix this issue. I want to log both magentos in same time on same browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of session and cookie in magento 2 is  belong to domain.
So you can change it in [image]

In Magento 1.9, following it at System > Configuration > Web > Cookie and Session Management

Comment: Great. I solved it by setting cookie path in sub domain magento as `/subdomain` .